# Suitable Router for +70 User

Tags: router

We need to purchase a new Router for our company (More than 70 user in one building) the required specification is: Load Balancing, 2 ADSL lines support, 3G Support as a backup plan.

What is the best router model for our buisness?

Than you in advance.